# Best practise for endpoint returning dynamic statistics data

Tags: .net, entity-framework, .net-core

Currently, I need to have an endpoint that can return statistics for a specific object, by a specific property.
For example, I have a property in that object, and i want to return the number of objects with a certain source.
Example:

```
Statistic by source 
{
twitter: 20, 
facebook: 30,
Instagram: 40,
}
```

But, i would also like to be able to use this endpoint for another statistic, for example, by source, and then another property (lets say age)
so it would be

```
twitter: {
under18: 10
adult: 5
senior: 5

}
facebook...
```

and so on.
Or search by a completely different property, let's say location

```
{
  America: 20
  Asia: 30
  ....
}
```

what would be the best way to go about constructing such an endpoint (and is it even a good idea?)
Currently what I have in mind is returning a dictionary of dictionaries.
Or should i just bite the bullet and make a separate endpoint for all the statistics that might come up?

Comment: Will the same endpoint return differents format? Can it be a `json` format?

Comment: yeah, it can all be a json format.

Answer (score 0):

Your return class needs to be (or inherit from) a class like this one.

```
public class ExtensibleObject
{
    [JsonExtensionData]
    public JObject AdditionalData { get; set; } = new JObject();
}
```

The use of `JsonExtensionDataAttribute` is documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-handle-overflow)