# Deserialize issue in C# Json

Tags: c#, json

PageParameters have dynamic values. I tried to add it like below.

```
{
 "Message": [
    {
        "TextMessage": "Hello World", 
        "Notification": [{ 
        "Page": "Order",
        "OpenPage": true,
        "PageParameters":[ {"filedName": "400","filedvalue": "test","test": "444"}]      
     } ]
    }
    ]
}
```

C# Code

```
 var notification = notificationRequest?.NotificationMessage[0].ToString();            
 var NotificationObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<NotificationObj>(notification);


public class NotificationObj
{
    public string TextMessage { get; set; }
    public string AppName { get; set; }
    public List<Notifications> Notification { get; set; } 
}

public class Notifications
{       
    public string PageName { get; set; }
    public bool OpenPage { get; set; } 
    public List<PageParameter> PageParameters { get; set; } 
}


public class PageParameter
{
    List<string> PageParameters = new List<string>();
}
```

My PageParameter have dynamic values. Its getting multiple values. So i tried to add it as a List. But its not adding values when Deserialize Json. Other values are adding. Please help to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67466851/1901309). You essentially need to apply that on your `PageParameter` class

Answer (score 0):

`PageParameters` is an array of `Key-value pairs`, which would require the use of a `Dictionary` in C#.

Update `PageParameter` to the following and re-run your deserialization:

```
public class PageParameter
{
    Dictionary<string, string> PageParameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I added it but my PageParameters count showing as 0

Comment: prolly it should be public ... and maybe you should make it property instead field